# Laravel 5 - data not sending to queue job

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code:

```
protected $game;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(Game $game)
{
    $this->game = $game;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    dd($this->game);
}
```

which I am calling like so:

```
$game = Game::FindOrFail($game);
$job = (new EndGame($game))->delay(60);
dispatch($job);
```

However the `handle` method `dd` returns `null`

If I call `dd($game)` before I send it to the queue everything is fine.

Comment: May be a stupid check - do you have class YourJob extends Job implements SelfHandling

Comment: If you try to dd('Some string literal') from your handle method can you see the output

Comment: Did you declare the game variable?